# Selecting the correct MaxLag for Granger's Causality

Tags: programming

I have a developer who has created a python script to determine the granger's causality of several datasets that are approximately 3 years worth of daily data (approx 1100 data points for each time series). The script seems to run well but we are not sure what MaxLag we should choose. Our goal is to determine possible causalities AND to determine the lag time in the causality (1 day, 2 days, 7 days, 14 days, etc). Obviously, when we change the maxlag number from 1 to 15 we get very different numbers.

It is my understanding that the higher the MaxLag the more "analyses" are done on the time series which results in the high MaxLag numbers providing stronger causality results. That seemingly would be very helpful but only if we know what the actual "lag" is for the causality.

Appreciate any insights someone can provide on this.

Comment: Hi: most of the time, a top down approach is used. In other words, use a large number of lags and, as soon as you get an insignificant one, stop. This is assuming you're using some kind of VAR for estimation ? There's Schwert's algorithm also. I don't remember it exactly but it's in Eric Zivot's S+FInmetrics book if you have that. Finally,  note that there's no REAL ANSWER. They say that "finding the number of lags to use is an art rather than a science." I always take that as a nice way of saying that there's really no hard and fast way to do it nor "the truth".